# How to rearrange an equation for NMRI calculations

Tags: trigonometry

As [illustrated here](http://mriquestions.com/spoiled-gre-parameters.html) I have the following MRI (Nuclear Magnetic Resonance Imaging) equation which I would like to rearrange for T1:

$$
S = k\times[H]\times{\frac{sin(\alpha)\times(1-\epsilon^{\frac{-TR}{T_1}})}{1-cos(\alpha)\times\epsilon^{\frac{-TR}{T_1}}}}\times\epsilon^{\frac{-TE}{T_2}}
$$

I assume you'd start with:

$$
{\frac{S}{k\times[H]\times\epsilon^{\frac{-TE}{T_2}}}} = {\frac{sin(\alpha)\times(1-\epsilon^{\frac{-TR}{T_1}})}{1-cos(\alpha)\times\epsilon^{\frac{-TR}{T_1}}}}
$$

But at this point I'm stuck.  I think there are some trigonometric relationships you can use here to get the ${\frac{-TE}{T_2}}$ term by itself.  Perhaps some Euler "trick"?

Edits / suggestions / migration / deletion welcome.

Comment: The answer below is a nice one. But if you are using a heavily T1-weighted sequence where TE<<T2*, then the e^-TE/T2 term can be excluded, which makes it simpler. In that case you can estimate the k[H] product from a variable flip angle experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to rearrange for $T_1$, considering$$S = k\,[H]\,{\frac{\sin(\alpha)\,(1-\epsilon^{-\frac{TR}{T_1}})}{1-\cos(\alpha)\,\epsilon^{-\frac{TR}{T_1}}}}\,\epsilon^{-\frac{TE}{T_2}}\tag 1$$ let us change notations
$$s=\sin(\alpha)\qquad c=\cos(\alpha)\qquad x=\epsilon^{-\frac{TR}{T_1}}$$ which makes
$$S= k\,[H]\,{\frac{s\,(1-x)}{1-c\,x}}\,\epsilon^{-\frac{TE}{T_2}}\tag 2$$ So
$$\frac {S \epsilon^{\frac{TE}{T_2}} }{k[H]s}=\frac{1-x}{1-cx}$$ Using
$$K=\frac {S \epsilon^{\frac{TE}{T_2}} }{k[H]s}\implies K=\frac{1-x}{1-cx}\implies x=\frac{K-1}{c K-1}$$

So $$T_1=-\text{TE}\,\frac{ \log (\epsilon )}{\log (x)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's really obvious now you point it out!  * grin & facepalm *.  I'm confused by the last rearrangement though as I get $K=\frac{1-x}{1-cx}\implies K(1-cx)=1-x \implies K-Kcx=1-x \implies x-Kcx=1-K \implies x(1-Kc)=1-K \implies x=\frac{1-K}{1-Kc}$
I've proposed an edit for this which you can review as you see fit :)

Comment: And then the value of $T_1$ is different too.  I have suggested a second edit to correct that.

Comment: @AJP. For $x$ multiply top and bottom by $-1$

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.